# Checking for whitespace program in C not working properly

Tags: c, whitespace, removing-whitespace

I am trying to check for sequential whitespace in a file full of characters. I want my program to ignore more than 1 whitespace after a sequence of characters. Also, a tab will be replaced for a whitespace. I am opening a file and reading it, so don't worry about that part of the code, since it works. My code:

```
char ch;
char sentenceArray[1000];
int charCount = 0;

    while (1) {
        ch = getc(file);

        //If is some sort of space, check it
        if(ch == ' '){
            if(sentenceArray[charCount-1] != ' '){
                sentenceArray[charCount] = ' ';
            }
        }else if(ch == '\t'){
            if(sentenceArray[charCount-1] != ' '){
                sentenceArray[charCount] = ' ';
            }
        }else{
            printf("Not space");
            sentenceArray[charCount] = ch;
        }
        charCount++;
    }

void print()
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i<= charCount; i++){
        printf("%c", sentenceArray[i]);
    }
}
```

The only relevant line in main is:

`print();`

If I feed it a file:

`myprog < file1`

The contents of my file look like:

`Uno Dos  Tres   Cuatro    a`

Where the spaces are 1 in between Uno and Dos, 2 in between Dos and Tres, 3 in between Tres and Cuatro, and a tab in between Cuatro and a.

This is the output (I print the array):

`Uno Dos Tres  Cuatro a`

As you can see, my program successfully eliminates just 2 continuos spaces... if they are more, it just keeps on deleting two but if they are more, say 10, it only takes 2 out and then it prints 8 spaces.

Do you know why this is happening? What are the flaws in my code?

Thanks!

Comment: Side note: By accessing `sentenceArray[charCount-1]`, your program yields undefined behavior if the input starts with a white space.

Comment: Thanks for the side note! I will do the appropriate checking after I solve this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are incrementing `charCount` every time you get a new character. You should only be updating `charCount` when adding a new char to your output.

Otherwise you are going to be comparing to an unknown (or whatever `sentenceArray` is initialized to) value after the second space is encountered which will cause the check `if(sentenceArray[charCount-1] != ' ')` to result in true and add another space.

```
  //If is some sort of space, check it
    if ((ch == ' ') || (ch == '\t')){
        if((charCount == 0) || (sentenceArray[charCount-1] != ' '))
        {
            sentenceArray[charCount] = ' ';
            charCount++; // <-- added this here
        }
    }else{
        printf("Not space");
        sentenceArray[charCount] = ch;
        charCount++; // <-- added this here
    }
    // charCount++; <-- remove this
```

On a side note, you may want to look at using [isspace()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/isspace.html)

Comment: No problem. Adding some prints (or other debug info) inside each case makes it pretty easy to see what is going on. Simply printing the `charCount` in this case was all It needed.

Comment: Suggest removing `}else if(ch == '\t'){` block and changing previous block to `if(ch == ' ' || ch == '\t'){`.  As it is now, still UB should first char be `'\t'` and another `charCount++;` is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Code needs to keep track if the previous `char` was a white-space.

```
// char ch;
int ch;
char sentenceArray[1000];
int charCount = 0;
int previous_space = 0;

while ((ch = getc(file)) != EOF && charCount < 1000) {

    if (isspace(ch)) {
      if (!previous_space) {
        sentenceArray[charCount++] = ' ';
        previous_space = 1;
        }
      }
    else {
      sentenceArray[charCount++] = ch;
      previous_space = 0;
    }
}
```